# Bind keybord shortcuts to a MIDI keyboard?

Tags: key-bindings

I'm exploring the possibility of using a programmable keybord like this one:

https://storefront.expertkeys.com/startseite/28-expertkeys-ek-20-usb-tastatur-0700587547911.html

[image]

to expand and simplify my keyboard shortcuts.

Now I'm wondering if there is the possibility to use a musical MIDI keyboard instead? E.g. like this one:

https://www.akaipro.com/lpk25

[image]

This solution would be much cheaper and, in my opinion, "smarter".

Anyone have news of such a project?

Comment: You would need to check what keycodes your OS receives when you press keys on the MIDI keyboard.  If you're on Linux, you can use [`xev`](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/man/man1/xev.1.xhtml) to do so.

Comment: I'm on Linux. Thanks!

Comment: there is a package on ELPA, https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/midi-kbd.html

This allows you to use a MIDI device for input to Emacs. It turns key presses on the MIDI device into key-events which you must bind to commands.
I have not used this so do not know what it really does for you.

By the way, once you have set up your MIDI keyboard using midi-kbd you can
check the key-events it has assigned to key presses on the MIDI keyboard by
typing "C-h k" and then pressing the key you are interested in on the MIDI
keyboard.

Comment: [maybe OT] some tried to connect multiple keyboards and change the keymap of one of the them
https://superuser.com/a/787910/203364

Comment: Kind of OT, but I guess it's a consequence of the question.  OTOH, it would be good to make your answer a bit more complete, e.g. pointing to `setxkbdmap` and `-device` to make the answer useful even without folling the link.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest not using a midi keyboard, but instead, using any keyboard which is capable of running `QMK` firmware.

This has the following advantages:

- It can work in any application and doesn't rely on configuring your operating system/software for non-standard input devices *(from the perspective of using it for keyboard shortcuts at least).*
- You can enable modifier keys to switch layers.
- You can configure keys to run multiple keystrokes (including typing in text).
- It can record/playback macros.

You could use the [plank keyboard](https://ergodox-ez.com/pages/planck) or [lets-split](https://falba.tech) as a large num-pad, programming F-Keys 13..24, as well as [other available keys](https://beta.docs.qmk.fm/reference/keycodes).

For example, you could bind each key to a `Hyper-[A-Z]` combination, assuming you're not already using the Hyper modifier elsewhere.

See [qmk/keyboards](https://github.com/qmk/qmk_firmware/tree/master/keyboards) for a full list of supported keyboards.

Comment: Interesting but not cheap at all. ;-)

Comment: QMK supports loads of keyboards: https://falba.tech have cheaper options (stand alone numpad's and lets-split may be viable alternatives).